# Unable to identify USER on bash script executed by udev

Tags: bash, debian, root, udev

I have created an udeve rule (on Debian) to copy files from sdcard when it is plug in:

```
# only do something for sdX
KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*", GOTO="my_mount_end"
#
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", ENV{PARTN}=="1",  RUN+="/usr/bin/at -M -f /usr/local/bin/SCRIPT now"    
# exit
LABEL="my_mount_end"
#
```

`/usr/local/bin/SCRIPT` is a bash script on which I want to differentiate classical use from current user and usage via the udev rule. Thus, I am trying to identify the USER that runs the script but $USER, $EUID and $(id -u) give nothing. How can I especially identify that root runs the script?

Comment: I would say `id -u` or `id -ru` should work, but I have no experience with udev. Have you considered e.g. `ENV{RUN_FROM_UDEV}=="yes"` and checking this in the script? I think `at` will pass the environment. Anyone using the script "classically" will be able to fool it by setting this environment variable anyway. Is this acceptable?